# Find negative values in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell

I have the following **cell** of data

lines{1}

ans =

```
'1000.0    -7    NaN    NaN    70'     
'995.0     32   11.0    6.9    -7'    
'962.0    313    8.8    6.2    84'  
'925.0    640    6.2    5.5    95'
```

I would  test if the columns number 2,3,5 have negative values and then delete the relative rows. In this case the result will be:

```
962.0    313    8.8    6.2     84  
925.0    640    6.2    5.5     95
```

**I updated my post** because I deleted some rows and then I could convert to a numerical matrix but I receive the message: "Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

Comment: Why is this in a cell array? Can't you just convert it to a normal array?

Comment: You should convert your cell to a numerical matrix and then you can either loop over your rows and copy each row to a new matrix ignoring those who are negative in column 2,3 or 5 (if-cases). Or use logical indexing to do the same. But I would definetely recommend to copy the data to a numerical matrix and work with that one. At the end just return the resulting matrix to a cell (if needed)

Comment: This cell contains other rows that are not number or 'nan' values, therefore I can't convert it to a numerical matrix but I must to read it by lines = textscan(cell2mat(t), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); and choose only some rows.

Comment: I updated my example, now I could convert my cell to a numerical matrix and then deleting the row as explained above.

Comment: @Mixo Is your data really strings with spaces separating the numbers?? I doubt it. Please post a proper example of the data that can be copied an pasted straight into matlab as the correct cell matrix.'

Comment: Yes, there are spaces that separate the numbers. The cell was created by regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want to iterate in that cell, and probably what people is suggeting you ( create a normal array) is the best way to approach. But if you really need to do it this way, here is a code that will do the work:

```
clear; clc;

lines{1}=['1000.0    -7    NaN    NaN    70',  
'995.0     32   11.0    6.9    -7',    
'962.0    313    8.8    6.2    84',  
'925.0    640    6.2    5.5    95' ]


cols=[2,3,5];                        % Colums to check for negatives

auxdata=str2num(lines{1});
del=sum((auxdata(:,cols)<0)');
indx=1:size(lines{1},1);
del=del.*(1:size(lines{1},1));
del(~del)=[];
lines{1}(del,:)=[];
data=str2num(lines{1})              % non-deleted numerical data
```

With this code youll have the result in double in the variable `data` and the string rows deleted from the cell.

This code is easily converted to a `for` for different `lines{ii}`

Comment: at the first line I receive: "Undefined function 'lt' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

Comment: @Mixo In my code there is no any "It" anywhere, so you are probably inserting that by yourself

Comment: I just did a copy and paste...I do not understand

Comment: With the code: del=sum((lines{1}<0)'); I receive the error message above, with del=sum((lines{1}{1}<0)'); I do not receive error but the code does not delete any row

Comment: @Mixo Are you jsut copy pasting the code I pisted or did you modify something (e.g. insert more data or you own data)

Comment: I notice that your data are delimited by brackets, instead my date have different format, you can see at my first one post that I have updated. Thank you for you interest

Comment: @Mixo So your data are strings? and do you wnat the result to be strings or rows of numbers? and do you want to delete the string rows from the cell or just extract the ones that have not any negative?

Comment: I want the result to be numbers and i want to delete the rows from the cell that have negative values in some columns (e.g.:2,3,5)

Comment: Ok, It's fine thank you. I just modify all "lines{1}" to "lines{1}{i}" for analyzing the i-th row and I receive an empty row [0x46 char] on the cell. Is it possible to delete the row? That is obtain the cell only without the i-th rom.

Answer (score 3):

```
M = cell2mat(C)
M(~any(M(:,[2,3,5])<0,2),:)
```

Comment: I tried to convert my cell but I receive the message "Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent" I think because there is not a semicolon to the end of each row. How could I to add it? Do you have an idea or suggestion?

Comment: @Mixo You should put up a proper representative example of your data. This method works for the data you posted, if your data is in a different form then you should update your example to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a cell array `lines` of matrices.

```
column_ = [2 3 5];
out1 = cellfun(@(a)({a((~any(a(:,column_)<0,2)),:)}),lines);
```

`out1` will be a cell array consisting of the matrices that you want to the corresponding matrices of `lines`.